# My Javascript PONG game doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have followed a tutorial on a PONG game, but when I open the HTML file in Chrome it doesn't work! I am a noob at HTML, so please help!
There are some comments saying what each part should do. If I have the file open in Chrome, it gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null

I also have tried putting the code through a HTML Checker, but it says everything is correct!

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Pong
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function( callback ){
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
        })();
        window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function() {
        return window.cancelAnimationFrame          ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        clearTimeout
        } )();
        // Initialize canvas and required variables
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), // Create canvas context
        W = window.innerWidth, // Window's width
        H = window.innerHeight, // Window's height
        particles = [], // Array containing particles
        ball = {}, // Ball object
        paddles = [2], // Array containing two paddles
        mouse = {}, // Mouse object to store it's current position
        points = 0, // Varialbe to store points
        fps = 60, // Max FPS (frames per second)
        particlesCount = 20, // Number of sparks when ball strikes the paddle
        flag = 0, // Flag variable which is changed on collision
        particlePos = {}, // Object to contain the position of collision
        multipler = 1, // Varialbe to control the direction of sparks
        startBtn = {}, // Start button object
        restartBtn = {}, // Restart button object
        over = 0, // flag varialbe, cahnged when the game is over
        init, // variable to initialize animation
        paddleHit;
        // Add mousemove and mousedown events to the canvas
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackPosition, true);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", btnClick, true);
        // Initialise the collision sound
        collision = document.getElementById("collide");
        // Set the canvas's height and width to full screen
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
        // Function to paint canvas
        function paintCanvas() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
        }
        // Function for creating paddles
        function Paddle(pos) {
        // Height and width
        this.h = 5;
        this.w = 150;

        // Paddle's position
        this.x = W/2 - this.w/2;
        this.y = (pos == "top") ? 0 : H - this.h;

        }
        // Push two new paddles into the paddles[] array
        paddles.push(new Paddle("bottom"));
        paddles.push(new Paddle("top"));
        // Ball object
        ball = {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        r: 5,
        c: "white",
        vx: 4,
        vy: 8,

        // Function for drawing ball on canvas
        draw: function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        }
        };
        // Start Button object
        startBtn = {
        w: 100,
        h: 50,
        x: W/2 - 50,
        y: H/2 - 25,

        draw: function() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.lineWidth = "2";
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

        ctx.font = "18px Arial, sans-serif";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStlye = "white";
        ctx.fillText("Start", W/2, H/2 );
        }
        };
        // Restart Button object
        restartBtn = {
        w: 100,
        h: 50,
        x: W/2 - 50,
        y: H/2 - 50,

        draw: function() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.lineWidth = "2";
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

        ctx.font = "18px Arial, sans-serif";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStlye = "white";
        ctx.fillText("Restart", W/2, H/2 - 25 );
        }
        };
        // Function for creating particles object
        function createParticles(x, y, m) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;

        this.radius = 1.2;

        this.vx = -1.5 + Math.random()*3;
        this.vy = m * Math.random()*1.5;
        }
        // Draw everything on canvas
        function draw() {
        paintCanvas();
        for(var i = 0; i < paddles.length; i++) {
        p = paddles[i];

        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
        }

        ball.draw();
        update();
        }
        // Function to increase speed after every 5 points
        function increaseSpd() {
        if(points % 4 == 0) {
        if(Math.abs(ball.vx) < 15) {
            ball.vx += (ball.vx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            ball.vy += (ball.vy < 0) ? -2 : 2;
        }
        }
        }
        // Track the position of mouse cursor
        function trackPosition(e) {
        mouse.x = e.pageX;
        mouse.y = e.pageY;
        }
        // Function to update positions, score and everything.
        // Basically, the main game logic is defined here
        function update() {

        // Update scores
        updateScore();

        // Move the paddles on mouse move
        if(mouse.x && mouse.y) {
        for(var i = 1; i < paddles.length; i++) {
            p = paddles[i];
            p.x = mouse.x - p.w/2;
                }
        }

        // Move the ball
        ball.x += ball.vx;
        ball.y += ball.vy;

        // Collision with paddles
        p1 = paddles[1];
        p2 = paddles[2];

        // If the ball strikes with paddles,
        // invert the y-velocity vector of ball,
        // increment the points, play the collision sound,
        // save collision's position so that sparks can be
        // emitted from that position, set the flag variable,
        // and change the multiplier
        if(collides(ball, p1)) {
        collideAction(ball, p1);
        }


        else if(collides(ball, p2)) {
        collideAction(ball, p2);
        }

        else {
        // Collide with walls, If the ball hits the top/bottom,
        // walls, run gameOver() function
        if(ball.y + ball.r > H) {
            ball.y = H - ball.r;
            gameOver();
        }

        else if(ball.y < 0) {
            ball.y = ball.r;
            gameOver();
        }

        // If ball strikes the vertical walls, invert the
        // x-velocity vector of ball
        if(ball.x + ball.r > W) {
            ball.vx = -ball.vx;
            ball.x = W - ball.r;
        }

        else if(ball.x -ball.r < 0) {
            ball.vx = -ball.vx;
            ball.x = ball.r;
        }
        }



        // If flag is set, push the particles
        if(flag == 1) {
        for(var k = 0; k < particlesCount; k++) {
            particles.push(new createParticles(particlePos.x, particlePos.y, multiplier));
        }
        }

        // Emit particles/sparks
        emitParticles();

        // reset flag
        flag = 0;
        }
        //Function to check collision between ball and one of
        //the paddles
        function collides(b, p) {
        if(b.x + ball.r >= p.x && b.x - ball.r <=p.x + p.w) {
        if(b.y >= (p.y - p.h) && p.y > 0){
            paddleHit = 1;
            return true;
        }

        else if(b.y <= p.h && p.y == 0) {
            paddleHit = 2;
            return true;
        }

        else return false;
        }
        }
        //Do this when collides == true
        function collideAction(ball, p) {
        ball.vy = -ball.vy;

        if(paddleHit == 1) {
        ball.y = p.y - p.h;
        particlePos.y = ball.y + ball.r;
            multiplier = -1;
        }

        else if(paddleHit == 2) {
        ball.y = p.h + ball.r;
        particlePos.y = ball.y - ball.r;
            multiplier = 1;
        }

        points++;
        increaseSpd();

        if(collision) {
        if(points > 0)
            collision.pause();

        collision.currentTime = 0;
        collision.play();
        }

        particlePos.x = ball.x;
        flag = 1;
        }
        // Function for emitting particles
        function emitParticles() {
        for(var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
        par = particles[j];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        if (par.radius > 0) {
            ctx.arc(par.x, par.y, par.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        }
            ctx.fill();

        par.x += par.vx;
        par.y += par.vy;

        // Reduce radius so that the particles die after a few seconds
        par.radius = Math.max(par.radius - 0.05, 0.0);

        }
        }
        // Function for updating score
        function updateScore() {
        ctx.fillStlye = "white";
        ctx.font = "16px Arial, sans-serif";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Score: " + points, 20, 20 );
        }
        // Function to run when the game overs
        function gameOver() {
        ctx.fillStlye = "white";
        ctx.font = "20px Arial, sans-serif";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText("Game Over - You scored "+points+" points!", W/2, H/2 + 25 );

        // Stop the Animation
        cancelRequestAnimFrame(init);

        // Set the over flag
        over = 1;

        // Show the restart button
        restartBtn.draw();
        }
        // Function for running the whole animation
        function animloop() {
        init = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
        draw();
        }
        // Function to execute at startup
        function startScreen() {
        draw();
        startBtn.draw();
        }
        // On button click (Restart and start)
        function btnClick(e) {

        // Variables for storing mouse position on click
        var mx = e.pageX,
            my = e.pageY;

        // Click start button
        if(mx >= startBtn.x && mx <= startBtn.x + startBtn.w) {
        animloop();

        // Delete the start button after clicking it
        startBtn = {};
        }

        // If the game is over, and the restart button is clicked
        if(over == 1) {
        if(mx >= restartBtn.x && mx <= restartBtn.x + restartBtn.w) {
            ball.x = 20;
            ball.y = 20;
            points = 0;
            ball.vx = 4;
            ball.vy = 8;
            animloop();

            over = 0;
        }
        }
        }
        // Show the start screen
        startScreen();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a problem with your javascript, not HTML. The javascript is calling a method `getContext` on something that is empty.

Comment: Your problem is in your Javascript, not your HTML. If you don't understand the difference I suggest you find a simpler tutorial to get started on.

Comment: Mike W I do understand the difference, I just didn't understand the problem. I knew that it was the JavaScript, but I could not think of a different way to phrase my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your script runs:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), // Create canvas context
```

*Before* the `canvas` element exists:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Move the  section to the *bottom* of the HTML, and things should work better.

```
<body>
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
   <script>
      <!-- Move all your script here -->
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I know, I've been playing it!